# How to implement check/uncheck recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got grid recycler view. For example I have 10 items in it. So I need to build logic that will allow me click on item 6 so after click the item 6 will change background to red. So after that all items has white background and only number 6 has red. After another click on item 6 since its already has red background we need to change it back to white. This way I can check/uncheck all items in the grid. Please give idea or pseudo code how to implement it

Comment: radio list or a list of check box?

Answer (score 0):

use below code in your customAdapter

```
class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

  public TestViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            <<your code>>

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }   
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {

     int color = ((ColorDrawable) view.getBackground()).getColor();

     if ( color == view.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
     {
        view.setBackgroundColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
     }
     else
     {
        view.setBackgroundColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
     }
  }
}
```